# How can I compare dictionary keys and array?

Tags: arrays, swift

My question is I have one array it has item names and I have dictionary, this dictionary have key values item names (same as array) and values any kind of int values. My question is that how can I get exactly same item name when I compare these two(array and dictionary) and how can I get this value from dictionary? I tried that code but it didn't get correct value.

```
for j in arrays.keys {
    for r in orderItemName {
        if j == r{
            // do stuff
        }
     }
}
```

How can I get same item name and get value of that item name ?

my dictionary: ["denemedir": 1, "deneme 3": 2, "deneme 2 dir": 2]

my array: ["denemedir", "deneme 2 dir", "deneme 3"]

I want to get 1 for denemedir, 2 for deneme 3 and 2 for deneme 2 dir.

Comment: What you mean by `it didn't get correct value` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need to compare the key, You can get the values like:

```
for key in orderItemName {
   //You can access the value from dictionary using -> arrays[key]
}
```